# Split Balance Amount Between Current Date and End Date

Tags: sql-server

Can any one help me how to split Balance Amount between `Current Date` and `End Date` in `Sql Server 2008`

Example:

```
BalanceAmount  TodaysDate   NewEnddate   2015-11     2015-12       2016-01                      

$14117.64      10/29/2015   1/4/2016     $6,321.33   $6,532.04     $842.84
```

Comment: 1. Learn to format your questions. Not that hard, and read [ask] if you need help. 2. You shouldn't ask for code, you should ask for help with your own code, read [ask] (again).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because minimal effort in solving the problem has not been shown, neither was minimal effort to post a good post was shown.

Comment: Can you show your table structure? you want to split amount monthwise?

Comment: This is the table structure CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Top_Suppliers](
 [Id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PO_Nuber] [date] NULL, --Its a Unique number like SSD2835987
 [PO_Start_Date] [date] NULL,
 [PO_End_Date_New] [date] NULL,
 [PO_Amount] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Top_Suppliers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: I need to split amount between Start Date and PO_End_Date_New and splited amount has to display over columns

Comment: Example :  Today date is 10/29/2015 and New End date
 is 1/4/2016 amount has to split into months in columns like for 2015-11,2015-12,2016-01

Comment: you can use dynamic pivot to do this

Comment: Can you provide me a query or stored procedure I am trying but not getting how to do it

Comment: Can you Please provide me a query or stored procedure waiting for your reply

Comment: see the answers. I have tried a dynamic sql with sample data. check whether it worked out for you

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. I have used dynamic sql for getting number of months in the table.

```
  CREATE TABLE mnth  (monthdate datetime, amount int)

  insert into mnth values 
  ('2015-01-04', 100),
  ('2015-01-05', 100), 
  ('2016-01-05', 200), 
  ('2016-01-05', 300), 
  ('2016-02-05', 400),
  ('2017-01-05', 500)


DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sum     int,
        @maxdate datetime ,
        @mindate datetime ;

 SET @columns = N'';
 SELECT @columns += N', ' + QUOTENAME(cast(year(monthdate) as varchar)+'-'+ cast(month(monthdate) as varchar))
            FROM mnth 
            GROUP BY cast(year(monthdate) as varchar)+'-'+ cast(month(monthdate) as varchar)


 select @sum = sum(amount) from mnth
 select @maxdate = max(monthdate)from mnth
 select @mindate = GETDATE()


 SET @sql = N'

 SELECT '+CAST(@sum as nvarchar)+' as total, '+''''+CONVERT(varchar(20),@maxdate,101)+''''+' as lastdate, '+
 +''''+CONVERT(varchar(10),@mindate,101)+''''+ ' as startdate,'+ STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
 FROM
 (
 select amount, cast(year(monthdate) as varchar) +''-''+ cast(month(monthdate) as varchar) AS mnthdate from mnth
 ) AS j
 PIVOT
 (
 SUM(amount) FOR mnthdate IN ('
 + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
 + ')
 ) AS p;';
 PRINT @sql;
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: can you try to split amount between two date columns ? I already have table and given you the structure

Comment: this query will split the amount for each date group

Comment: but i want amount to split it to months across current date and NewEnddate ,if current date is 11/29/2015 and NewEnddate  is 2/28/2016 then amount has to split into 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01 2016-02

Comment: i think above query will do the same. One change i did was, I pre-calcuated, total sum, start date, end date

Comment: can you give data structure in your table. so that i can check it once again

Comment: i your query where i have to give current date and end date and amount need to split across date range

Comment: and concat is not working sql server 2008, I am using it , instead of that i used this QUOTENAME(month(PO_End_Date_New)+'-'+year(PO_End_Date_New)) but its giving results in years not in months

Comment: instead concat , use like below                                                                                                                    select cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)+'-' +cast(month(getdate()) as varchar)

Comment: can you specify from where you took enddate value. I have changed startdate value as current date in the query now check it. Also removed concat function

Comment: yes in my table I have current date as start date and New End Date is some date value ,if current date is 11/29/2015 and NewEnddate is 2/28/2016 then amount has to split into 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01 2016-02

Comment: your query is summing the amount, it is suppose to split across months

Comment: for NewEnddate 1/4/2016 if amount is 14000 then it has to split into months from current date

Comment: what is the criteria for splitting the amount across months?

Comment: criteria is simple difference between dates is 60 days then it has to split to 2 months in a column like this :   Today's Date New End date 2015-11 2015-12 2016-01 are columns

Comment: if today and end date is 10/29/2015 1/4/2016
then amount value in each row has to split between these month in column

Comment: please give me your id or let me now how to share so that  I will share excel sheet where it has data

Comment: so you mean you want to equally divide the amount between each month?

Comment: I have sent you email please check

Comment: Can anyone help me on this